# Why did Kuroshitsuji II use new characters and plot?

Tags: black-butler

The second anime of *Kuroshitsuji*, *Kuroshitsuji II*, featured brand new characters including main characters Alois Trancy and Claude Faustus. The main characters of the original series, Ciel Phantomhive and Sebastian Michaelis, are still involved in the main plot, but the show isn't exactly focused on them.

Alois and Claude don't seem to appear in the *Kuroshitsuji* manga.

Is there any official discussion of why the second season of the anime created completely new main characters and a completely new plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how Toboso explained the matter in her journal:

> When the second season was announced on January 31st last winter, she received tremendous numbers of messages from the fans. The majority of the messages were criticisms against the absence of Ciel and Sebastian from the second season. "How dare you desert the fans, who have been waiting for the two?" "If you don't have affections for your characters, you don't deserve to be the author!" She and the producers had expected the bitter reactions because they intensionally hid Ciel and Sebastian from the announcement. In the first season, director Shinohara chose to bring the revenge of Ciel to an end and Toboso had approved it. The overwhelming enthusiasm of the fans had given the green light to the second season after that. Toboso asked the producers not to reset the finale of the first season. To meet two conflicting conditions: "We must not revive Ciel easily" versus "We want to show the two once again", she had been vigorously working on the scenario for half a year with other staff. In conclusion, they had created a new rival pair, Alois and Claude. With an intension of showing them "big" and dominant, Alois and Claude were placed in the main of the key illustrations and the trailer and Sakurai Takahiro and Mizuki Nana were assigned to them. Toboso said that the aim of the tricky announcement will be understood if you watch the series to the end.

Read more at http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=243708#FkjdSTxGYWPL8y1l.99